# What is  the definition of an invariant  of  elliptic curve?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

I know  what is the $j$-invariant  but I  am asking about a general definition  in sence of classical invariant theory.
The following possible definition seems  to be  wrong:
Consider an elliptic  curve $C: y^2=x^3+ax+b.$ Acting  by  the transformation 
$$
\begin{array}{c}
x=a_{1,1}x'+a_{1,2}y'+c_1,\\
y=a_{2,1}x'+a_{2,2}y'+c_2,
\end{array}
$$
we  get new curve $C'.$ The  invariant is a function of coefficients of  the curves  which is stable under above  transformation.   This definition  is  wrong   becouse  $C'$  now consists $y'^3$  and it isn't elliptic curve.

So, what is correct definition of an invariant of elliptic curve?

Comment: You are using a definition of "elliptic curve" which complots against you. 

Comment: The equation of $C'$ IS an elliptic curve, but it is not in the Weierstrass form. So the formula of $j$ is more complicated in this case. In Silvermann's book, transformation doesn't involve  $y'$ in $x'$.

Comment: Oh, so the transformation must be of the restricted form x=a1,2x′+c1.?

Comment: @Mariano, Auguste. I understood, the definition of el.curve should be more general: 
$a_0y^2+a_1y=b_0 x^3+b_1 x^2 +b_2 x+b_3,$
and the transformation should be restricted $x=a_{1,1}x'+c_1,\\ y=a_{2,1}x'+a_{2,2}y'+c_2.$ Then we may define invariants as usual. Thanks

Comment: http://books.google.com/books?id=CDP1zxFJLucC